# Change to default font-family of email in Joomla

Tags: php, web, joomla

The email body in defined in *PLG_USER_JOOMLA_NEW_USER_EMAIL_BODY*(string) in a .ini file. It is **plain text**.

```
PLG_USER_JOOMLA_NEW_USER_EMAIL_BODY= "Welcome to join XXXXXXXXXX %s %s %s %s %s"
```

I would like to know where I can add my css code in order to set the font-family of the email.

This is where the system construct the email. I not sure whether I should modify this file.

```
 // Compute the mail body.
   $emailBody = JText::sprintf(
        'PLG_USER_JOOMLA_NEW_USER_EMAIL_BODY',
        $user['name'],
        $this->app->get('sitename'),
        JUri::root(),
        $user['username'],
        $user['password_clear']
    );

   $mail = JFactory::getMailer()
        ->setSender(
            array(
                $this->app->get('mailfrom'),
                $this->app->get('fromname')
            )
        )
        ->addRecipient($user['email'])
        ->setSubject($emailSubject)
        ->setBody($emailBody);

    if (!$mail->Send())
    {
       $this->app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JERROR_SENDING_EMAIL'), 'warning');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think str_replace will do a trick

```
 $new_body=str_replace("<body>","<body style='font-family:Georgia, Serif !important'",$email_body);
   ->addRecipient($user['email'])
   ->setSubject($emailSubject)
   ->setBody($new_body);
```

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. I guess probably because of <body> tag doesn't exist in Joomla mail.

Comment: Try it with <html> or go to email and check which tags are used in email. but most definitely body tag can't be surpassed

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. We need to first convert the plain text to HTML, then anything works.

```
$mail->isHTML(TRUE); 

$html= array();
$html[] = '<div style="background: red">.$emailBody.</div>';
$mail->setBody(implode("\n", $html));
$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div tag to wrap the email body text and apply CSS to div tag.